# double authentication for https password protected password

Tags: https, authentication, opencart

I am hosting a customer's OpenCart store on my own domain hosting.  I have add-on domain in my CPanel for customer's domain and created sub domain for it to ease access.  Other than the double authentication everything works just fine.

I have a UCC 5 SSL Certificate with GoDaddy to cover my customer's domain
I am not sure if it is a `.htaccess` or CPanel than would fix this.

OpenCart store is physically under `www.mydomain.example/customer_store`, which is password protected

Add-on domain is set as `shop.customerdomain.example` and points to physical store location above.

In browser address bar, when entering `shop.customerdomain.example` it will request authentication twice, one for HTTP and one for HTTPS. Very similar to most questions on forums a the difference that working with an add-on domain. I've tried `StrictSSL` and `SSLRequest` but to no fix.

When entering `www.mydomain.example/customer_store authentication` is requested only once.

So my question is, if it can be solved in `.htaccess`, what would be the corresponding `RewriteCond` for add-on domain?